# wordpress, autopost, setting post_date from data date

Tags: wordpress, date

I have 2,000 pieces of data I want to import into my wordpress, as wp has many features that work nicely. I started doing it manually but then realized, that its easier to write a script to import it.

everything runs perfect!! one problem, I cannot get it to use the RELEASEDATE of my data as the POSTED date.

I have spend 2 days googling and using SO for resources, and everyone comes close, but some of the answers use wp inner coding structure which I do not want to do.  Here is what I have so far:

```
$title = htmlentities($title,ENT_NOQUOTES,$encoding); 
            $keywords = htmlentities($keywords,ENT_NOQUOTES,$encoding); 
            $content = array( 
                'title'=>$title, 
                'description'=>$body, 
                'mt_allow_comments'=>1,  // 1 to allow comments 
                'mt_allow_pings'=>0,  // 1 to allow trackbacks 
                'post_type'=>'post',
                'post_status' => 'draft',
                'publish' =>$pubdate,
                'mt_keywords'=>$keywords, 
                'categories'=>array($category) 
            ); 
            $params = array(0,$username,$password,$content,true); 
            $request = xmlrpc_encode_request('metaWeblog.newPost',$params); 
            $ch = curl_init();
```

That all works perfect but I cannot get the date to work. RELEASEDATE is formatted exactly like WP, 2011-03-04 14:33:21 etc.

It prints the date on the post, but the "posted" says the day i ran the script. in the above example I am sending RELEASEDATE to $pubdate. I know that the post_date is an object but not sure how to implement it here.

In short if i let this scrip run full I will have 2,000 post dated today!! :P

Answer (score 1):

[This page](http://mindsharestrategy.com/wp-xmlrpc-metaweblog/) list parameter accepted by **metaWeblog.newPost**.

From that page, you can use either '**date_created_gmt**' or '**dateCreated**' to store date data.

Comment: 'dateCreated'           => $pubdate,
                'date_created_gmt'      => $pubdate, well I added that to the above script, now it doesnt post anytihng. did I do that incorrectly?

Comment: ok fixed it to this:   'dateCreated'=>date(DATE_ISO8601,strtotime($pubdate)), now it post, but guess what, back to my original prob still using todays post date instead of pubdate

Comment: anyone else take a stab at this. if the date format is wrong, it will not post. if the date format is coorect, it ALWAYS defaults to todays date - not my data date.

Answer (score 1):

I do this in this way:

1. Use the [Incutio XML-RPC Library for PHP](http://scripts.incutio.com/xmlrpc/)
2. Code should looks like this:

   ```
   $client = new IXR_Client('http://wp-blog.com/xmlrpc.php');

   $post = array(
       'post_type'=> 'post',
       'title' => $title,
       'description' => $description,
       'date_created_gmt' => new IXR_Date(time()),
   );

   if (!$client->query('metaWeblog.newPost', '', $login, $password, $post, true))
   {
       die( 'Error while creating a new post' . $client->getErrorCode() ." : ". $client->getErrorMessage());
   }

   $post_id = $client->getResponse();
   ```

For me this works like a charm :-)

More detailed description about **ISO8601** and XML date format can be found here: [How to scedule a Post using XMLRPC / metaWeblog.newPost ??](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-scedule-a-post-using-xmlrpc-metaweblognewpost)